# For other outputs when checking break point

Tags: c#, visual-studio

While writing the code, I found that the results were different from those when we checked break points. The likely cause is the ToString function, which has different results when override. Why is the result different when you check break point after override?

When checking break point, call the function internally but do not know why.

My Code

```
using System;

namespace Test
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
            Console.Write("Test");  // Break Point
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {

        public override string ToString()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("???");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The results are as follows.

Check break point:
 ???
 Test

Non:
 Test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inspect `testClass` with the debugger, `ToString()` will be called by the debugger. This prints "???" to the console.

Comment: Do you know why ToString is called?

Comment: Because that's how it works: [_"if a C# object has an overridden ToString(), the debugger will call the override and show its result instead of the standard {<typeName>}."_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/enhancing-debugging-with-the-debugger-display-attributes)

Comment: @최민규 In order to display a text value the debugger uses the `ToString()` method for each object of interest. In this case a side effect of `TestClass.ToString()` is writing to the console. If the debugger had no reason to display the value, i.e. you are not using the Locals window, don't hover over the variable `testClass`, ..., it _might_ not invoke `testClass.ToString()`.